# Converting from DbContext to ObjectContext for webform in MVC application

Tags: webforms, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, objectcontext

I have an MVC5 application with EF 6.1 and the basic forms work great. Need to develop some complex forms though so webforms seemed the better option. Followed all the advice on converting DbContext to ObjectContext in order to use EntityDataSource for database communication but just get the **'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext to System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'** error despite updating to the latest version which is supposed to resolve this issue.

```
protected void EntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var db = new myDbContext(); 
    e.Context = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext; 
    //also tried e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
}
```

Would appreciate any advice on getting webforms running alongside MVC5, especially on getting the connection set up correctly for insert.